# Add modifications to each custom listview item

Tags: android, listview

So right now I have a custom listview adapter that adds another row when the user selects a item. The thing is, each item in the row should have a modification button where they can choose to add whatever modification it is (can choose more than one modification)

This is a food ordering app that when the item is selected, there should be another button in the list labeled "Modify", where a pop-up comes up and allows the user to choose what modification it wants by using checkbox. ("Less salt", "More sauce", etc). Each modification list is the same for each dish. When the user exits the popup and clicks on the same modify button, the checkboxes checked should stay there.

I originally created a Popup class where when the button is selected, there is an intent to jump to that Popup activity, but I couldn't find the relationship between the custom adapter and the Popup activity. I also tried using an AlertDialog to replace the Popup window, but could not find a way to save all the checked items and show which ones were selected before.

Here's my code

```
    modifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           builder.setTitle("Modification");

            final CharSequence[] modify_items = orderClass.getModifyList()
                    .toArray(new CharSequence[orderClass.getModifyList().size()]);
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(modify_items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        selectedList.add(indexSelected);
                        selectedItems.set(position, selectedList);
                    }
                    else if(selectedList.contains(indexSelected)){
                        selectedList.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                        selectedItems.set(position, selectedList);
                    }
                }
            })
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            Log.d("dialog", "Showing dialog");


        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put data in a holder structure(its kinda a class that holds variables)
then you can show data by index and theres is a relation between the list view index shown and the data index so when is a list view cell clicked you get the position then find it in the structure and post it to another activity or anything else to modify it remember you have to declare a flag to launch the activity else the app will crash i think its called activtyoutofbound index or something like this